# Calculadora crashando ao clicar nos botões de operação antes dos números

Tags: python, tkinter

quando executo a calculadora e clico nos botões de operações como o de soma ou divisão antes dos números o programa trava e para de funcionar, como posso consertar isso? usei o python e estou usando o tkinter

Comment: Para tratar dessa dúvida dentro do objetivo do site é importante restaurar e editar sua pergunta original conforme [já orientado lá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/588317/programa-crashando#comment1024514_588317]). Para evitar descentralização de informações, o campo de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado naquela postagem se restaurada.